# time format in different font sizes with swift

Tags: swift

Wondered if anyone could please help. I'm creating a basic iOS app that will display the time, but I'm having trouble setting different font sizes for the time label. Basically I need the time HH(hour):MM(minute) a different size font to the SS(seconds).

I've been looking at attributed text but I'm still unable to come up with some results.

Kind Regards.

Comment: you can also try with 3 different UILabel's, each one configured as you desire

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm just thinking the label will need to be updated frequently, would it be more efficient to have one label doing this instead of 3?

Comment: do not think that splitting a label into three different ones in one screen will ruin your performance

Comment: I suppose I could use two labels instead of three, one for the HH:MM and the other for SS, unless anyone knows how to achieve the same results with an attributed string.

Answer (score 0):

You can make extension for `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    @discardableResult func resize(_ text: String, _ size: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        append(NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: size)]))
        return self
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
let span = NSMutableAttributedString()
span.resize("HH:", 16.0).resize("MM:", 14.0).resize("SS", 18.0)
label.attributedText = span
```

In your case:

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let span = NSMutableAttributedString()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:"
span.resize(dateFormatter.string(from: date), 16.0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:"
span.resize(dateFormatter.string(from: date), 14.0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ss"
span.resize(dateFormatter.string(from: date), 18.0)
timeLabel1.attributedText = span
```

Comment: So I'm guessing I could use the following code to get this working somehow?    theTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.setTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        
        timeLabel1.text = dateString

Comment: Great, this works really well. Now I will just have to test this on multiple devices, I've setup some constraints, but not sure if its worth doing this programatically or using the interface builder.

Comment: Is it possible to programatically adjust the font size, depending on the device your viewing it on? I've also got constraints in place but the font size overrides this.

Comment: @Nightowl, my method use hardcoded values for font size and I think there is only one way how to adjust size depending on the device your viewing it on: if statements for device

Comment: Something like this: switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            print("iPhone 4")
        case 1136:
            print("iPhones 5/5s/5c/SE")
            fontSize1 = 170
            fontSize2 = 70
        case 1334:
            print("iPhones 6/6s/7/8")
        case 1920, 2208:
            fontSize1 = 200
            fontSize2 = 70
            print("iPhones 6Plus/6sPlus/7Plus/8Plus")
        case 2436:
            print("iPhoneX")
            fontSize1 = 250
            fontSize2 = 100
        default:
            print("unknown")
        }

Comment: @Nightowl, yeah